# JS/CSS Locking scroll on iOS Safari doesn't work when the browser interface is down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, mobile

I'm not sure if this question needs code but I will try to explain as well as possible.

I have a simple menu button that opens a full page overlay (w/ `opacity 0.9`)
so I want to be sure the use doesn't scroll the content in the page while the menu is open.
I implemented few techniques `(body: overflow hidden, position fixed)` but I realized that when you open the website on my iPhone Safari, the rules work only when the viewport has the browser interface fully visible (not the minimal ui on the right) but when in minimal Uimode, then the scroll can happen.

also since my design wants to be semi-transparent, the user can clearly see what's happening below..

any solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best solution I found so far is to use

```
touch-action: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

on the `modal` div. Not sure why but if apply the rule to the body doesn't work.
Of course this may prevent the modal to be scrollable...haven't tested yet, but at least is one less headache for today.